# The definition of a subspace gives conflicting answers?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra book the definition of a subspace is given as such.

A non-empty set of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ is called a subspace if it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition.

However, this the same book uses the term subspace when defining row space. This leads to conflicting logic.

A row space is the subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ that is spanned by the row vectors of a.

If a row space is subspace, that a non-empty set of vectors with certain properties, then how can it be a span at the same time.

What is the precise definition of a subspace and row space?

Comment: Spans are subspaces and a row space is a span, so...

Comment: What is $a$?  Anyway, the row space attached to a matrix is a particular example of a subspace.  Where do you see a conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to see what sort of "conflict" you see here.

A subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ is defined as you say. Given vectors $v_1,\dots, v_k\in\Bbb R^n$, the span of $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is the set of linear combinations of $v_1,\dots,v_k$.  It's an easy theorem that the span of $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Another term for "the span of $v_1,\dots,v_k$" is "the subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_k$". The rowspace of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ is the span of the rows of $A$. Hence the rowpsace of $A$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.

Those are the precise definitions - what's the problem?